# How can I create a custom converter/deserializer for @Header values in Spring Websocket

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a Websocket endpoint that I want to receive as header value not a string but an object.

This is how I defined the websocket endpoint

```
    @MessageMapping("/gather/{resource}")
    fun emitGatherEvent(@DestinationVariable resource: String, @Header context: Context) {     
        LOG.debug("gather endpoint called for client ${context.clientId} and character ${context.characterId} with resource '$resource'")
        eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Gather(resource), context.characterId)
    }
```

However Spring throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header com.barbarus.gameserver.websocket.Context]
```

I understand the issue but I have no idea how I can register a custom converter for the `Context` data class.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `FormatterRegistry`

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
 @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
     registry.addConverter(new YourCustomConverter());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What class do I need to extend for `YourCustomConverter` ?

Comment: Eg an interface `Converter`